# Implicitly bind the data context of the usercontrol when using content control with data template?

Tags: wpf, datacontext

Right now, the only thing that exists is a control template with a data template.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentVM,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <ContentControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HomeVM}">
      <Views:Home />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

In my views:home, I didn't set the data context to my homeviewmodel class. But when I bind a property on my button to a property of my homeviewmodel. it just works like magic, can someone explain this sorcery?

Comment: How about this, do you have any idea how it works?
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentVM,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:HomeVM}">
                    <Views:Home/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>

in my views:home i didn't set the data context but it magically binds to my homeVM class, I have so many questions in mind like what was happening or is this a work of sorcery.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Apologies,I just edited my comment.

Comment: Do not show code in comments, edit the question instead.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking. However, when the CurrentVM property and hence the Content of the ContentControl holds a HomeVM instance, the DataTemplate is applied to the ContentTemplate property of the ContentControl. This will create a Home instance that inherits its DataContext from the ContentControl, i.e. gets the Content object as its DataContext.

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Content Binding is pointless. It has no effect at all.

Comment: Thanks clemens you answered all my question it is enough to know that the value of CurrentVM will applied to the data context of my home instance.
By the way i am tryuing to create a navigation in my views hehe so later on I will add a data template for the remaining views Thanks A lot man.

Comment: I know that I can use Iframe for an alternative but I just want to do it in that way so that I can learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

> can someone explain this sorcery?

For binding, the initial control's `DataContext` is examined. If it is not null, the binding is attempted at that point for the property specified. If the `DataContext` is null (not that the binding failed mind you), then control's parent's `DataContext` is looked at and the same happens. That process continues until the main page's `DataContext` is finally looked at.

Somewhere in your chain, a parent's context was non null with the VM, *which you have set*, and your other control/situation appeared to work without having to do anything for that control and it bound itself to the property of the object held in the `DataContext`.